# How to disable JS animation if you see it more than once?

Tags: javascript, laravel, svg

I have a project in laravel 5.8. In the main side I have animation with svg elements. There is three letters JJK, and they appears one after one with some timeout. There is a function in JS to take care of it.

The animation is ok when you came the first time to website, but I would like to stop animation after you had seen it once. For example if you go to subpage from the main page and then you go back, the animation slows down the side rendering for 4 seconds. I would like to change it. Limit the appearance of the animation to one time.

There is the svg elements in my view:

```
<div class="header-col main-logo-col-2   col-xl-2 offset-xl-1">
    <svg class="main-logo-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 269 162.2">
        <g id="outlined">
            <g id="jaciubek-outlined">
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M20.6,1.7v24.9c0,3-0.8,5.2-2.4,6.8c-1.6,1.6-3.8,2.4-6.7,2.4c-3.2,0-5.6-0.9-7.4-2.7 c-1.6-1.6-2.4-3.8-2.6-6.7h3.7c0.1,1.7,0.6,3.1,1.4,4.1c1,1.3,2.6,2,4.6,2c1.9,0,3.4-0.6,4.3-1.8c0.9-1.1,1.3-2.5,1.3-4.1V1.7 H20.6 M21.6,0.7h-5.8v25.9c0,1.4-0.4,2.6-1.1,3.5s-1.9,1.4-3.5,1.4c-1.7,0-3-0.6-3.8-1.6s-1.2-2.6-1.2-4.5H0.5 c0,3.6,0.9,6.4,2.9,8.4s4.7,3,8.1,3c3.1,0,5.6-0.9,7.4-2.7c1.8-1.8,2.7-4.3,2.7-7.5L21.6,0.7L21.6,0.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M49.8,2.3l12.4,33.1h-4.1l-2.5-7l-0.2-0.7h-0.7H39.6h-0.7l-0.2,0.7l-2.5,7h-4L44.6,2.3L49.8,2.3 M39.8,25.2 h1.4H53h1.4l-0.5-1.3L48,7.2l-0.9-2.7l-0.9,2.7l-5.9,16.7L39.8,25.2 M50.5,1.3h-6.6L30.7,36.4h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7h6.2 L50.5,1.3L50.5,1.3z M41.2,24.2l5.9-16.7L53,24.2H41.2L41.2,24.2z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M89.5,1.5L89.5,1.5c3.8,0,7.1,1,9.8,3c2.4,1.8,4.1,4.2,5.2,7.2h-4.1c-0.9-2-2.3-3.7-4.1-4.9 c-1.9-1.4-4.4-2.1-7.4-2.1c-2.3,0-4.4,0.6-6.2,1.7c-1.9,1.1-3.3,2.8-4.3,4.9c-1,1.9-1.5,4.3-1.5,7.2c0,2.7,0.5,5,1.5,7.2 c1.1,2,2.5,3.7,4.2,4.9l0,0l0,0c2,1.2,4,1.7,6.2,1.7c2.9,0,5.3-0.7,7.4-2.1c1.8-1.3,3.2-3,4.1-4.9h4.1c-1,3-2.7,5.4-5.2,7.2 c-2.7,2.1-6.1,3.1-10.3,3.1c-3.1,0-6-0.7-8.5-2.2c-2.4-1.4-4.3-3.4-5.6-6c-1.3-2.5-2-5.6-2-8.9c0-3.4,0.7-6.4,2-8.9 C76.2,7,78,5,80.4,3.6c2.4-1.4,5.1-2.2,8.5-2.2C89.2,1.5,89.4,1.5,89.5,1.5 M89.5,0.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5,0c-3.4,0-6.4,0.7-9,2.3 c-2.6,1.5-4.6,3.7-6,6.4s-2.1,5.9-2.1,9.4s0.7,6.7,2.1,9.4c1.4,2.7,3.4,4.9,6,6.4s5.6,2.3,9,2.3c4.4,0,8-1.1,10.9-3.3 c2.9-2.2,4.9-5.2,5.9-9h-6.1c-0.8,2.1-2.2,3.8-4,5.1c-1.9,1.3-4.1,1.9-6.8,1.9c-2.1,0-4-0.6-5.7-1.6c-1.6-1.1-2.9-2.6-3.9-4.5 c-0.9-1.9-1.4-4.1-1.4-6.7c0-2.6,0.4-4.9,1.4-6.8c0.9-2,2.2-3.5,3.9-4.5c1.7-1.1,3.6-1.6,5.7-1.6c2.7,0,5,0.6,6.8,1.9 c1.8,1.2,3.2,2.9,4,5.1h6.1c-1-3.8-3-6.8-5.9-9C97.1,1.6,93.6,0.5,89.5,0.5L89.5,0.5z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M121.4,1.7v33.7h-3.8V1.7H121.4 M122.4,0.7h-5.8v35.7h5.8V0.7L122.4,0.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M160.6,1.7v20.2c0,4.6-1.2,8.1-3.5,10.4c-2.3,2.3-5.5,3.5-9.3,3.5s-6.9-1.2-9.2-3.5 c-2.3-2.3-3.4-5.7-3.4-10.4V1.7h3.7v20.2c0,3.4,0.8,6,2.3,7.8s3.8,2.6,6.7,2.6c2.7,0,4.9-0.9,6.5-2.6c1.6-1.7,2.4-4.3,2.4-7.8V1.7 H160.6 M161.6,0.7h-5.8v21.2c0,3.2-0.7,5.6-2.1,7.1c-1.4,1.5-3.3,2.3-5.8,2.3s-4.5-0.7-5.9-2.3s-2.1-3.9-2.1-7.1V0.7h-5.7v21.2 c0,4.9,1.2,8.6,3.7,11.1s5.8,3.8,9.9,3.8s7.5-1.3,10-3.8s3.8-6.2,3.8-11.1L161.6,0.7L161.6,0.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M187.4,1.7c3.3,0,5.8,0.7,7.6,2.2c1.7,1.4,2.5,3.4,2.5,5.8c0,2-0.5,3.6-1.6,4.8c-1,1.2-2.4,2-4.2,2.5l-3.9,1 l4,0.9c2.1,0.5,3.6,1.4,4.7,2.8c1.2,1.5,1.8,3.2,1.8,5.1c0,2.6-0.9,4.7-2.6,6.2c-1.8,1.6-4.6,2.4-8.1,2.4h-13.2V1.7H187.4 M178.2,17.1h1h7.1c2.2,0,3.9-0.5,5.2-1.6l0,0l0,0c1.3-1.2,1.9-2.7,1.9-4.7s-0.7-3.6-1.9-4.6c-1.2-1.1-3.1-1.7-5.5-1.7h-6.9h-1v1 v10.7v0.9 M178.2,32.7h1h7.3c2.4,0,4.4-0.6,5.7-1.7c1.4-1.2,2.2-2.9,2.2-5s-0.7-3.8-2.2-5c-1.4-1.1-3.3-1.7-5.7-1.7h-7.3h-1v1 v11.4V32.7 M187.4,0.7h-14v35.7h14.2c3.8,0,6.7-0.9,8.7-2.6c2-1.7,3-4.1,3-7c0-2.2-0.7-4.1-2-5.7c-1.3-1.6-3.1-2.6-5.3-3.1 c1.9-0.5,3.5-1.4,4.7-2.8c1.2-1.4,1.8-3.2,1.8-5.5c0-2.8-1-5-2.9-6.6C193.7,1.5,190.9,0.7,187.4,0.7L187.4,0.7z M179.2,5.4h6.9 c2.2,0,3.8,0.5,4.8,1.4c1.1,0.9,1.6,2.2,1.6,3.9c0,1.7-0.5,3-1.6,4c-1.1,0.9-2.6,1.4-4.6,1.4h-7.1L179.2,5.4L179.2,5.4L179.2,5.4 L179.2,5.4z M179.2,31.7V20.3h7.3c2.2,0,3.9,0.5,5.1,1.5c1.2,1,1.8,2.4,1.8,4.2s-0.6,3.2-1.8,4.2s-2.9,1.5-5.1,1.5L179.2,31.7 L179.2,31.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M229.2,1.7v2.7h-13.6h-1v1v10.8v1h1h12.1v2.4h-12.1h-1v1v11.1v1h1h13.6v2.7h-18.4V1.7H229.2 M230.2,0.7h-20.4 v35.7h20.4v-4.7h-14.6V20.6h13.1v-4.4h-13.1V5.4h14.6V0.7L230.2,0.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M265.7,1.7l-14.3,16l-0.6,0.7l0.6,0.7l14.3,16.3h-4.4l-13.8-16.1l-0.6-0.8l0.6-0.7l13.9-16.1L265.7,1.7 M245.7,1.7v15.4v2.7v0.1v15.5h-3.8V1.7H245.7 M267.9,0.7h-7l-14.2,16.4V0.7h-5.8v35.7h5.8V19.9l14.1,16.5h7.1l-15.8-18L267.9,0.7 L267.9,0.7z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="janiga-outlined">
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M20.6,64.1V89c0,3-0.8,5.2-2.4,6.8c-1.6,1.6-3.8,2.4-6.7,2.4c-3.2,0-5.6-0.9-7.4-2.7 c-1.6-1.6-2.4-3.8-2.6-6.7h3.7c0.1,1.7,0.6,3.1,1.4,4.1c1,1.3,2.6,2,4.6,2c1.9,0,3.4-0.6,4.3-1.8c0.9-1.1,1.3-2.5,1.3-4.1V64.1 H20.6 M21.6,63.1h-5.8V89c0,1.4-0.4,2.6-1.1,3.5s-1.9,1.4-3.5,1.4c-1.7,0-3-0.6-3.8-1.6s-1.2-2.5-1.2-4.5H0.5 c0,3.6,0.9,6.4,2.9,8.4s4.7,3,8.1,3c3.1,0,5.6-0.9,7.4-2.7c1.8-1.8,2.7-4.3,2.7-7.5L21.6,63.1L21.6,63.1z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M49.8,64.7l12.4,33.1h-4.1l-2.5-7l-0.2-0.7h-0.7H39.6h-0.7l-0.2,0.7l-2.5,7h-4l12.4-33.1H49.8 M39.8,87.6h1.4 H53h1.4l-0.5-1.3L48,69.6l-0.9-2.7l-0.9,2.7l-5.9,16.7L39.8,87.6 M50.5,63.7h-6.6L30.7,98.8h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7h6.2 L50.5,63.7L50.5,63.7z M41.2,86.6l5.9-16.7L53,86.6H41.2L41.2,86.6z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M100.9,64.2v33.6h-4.3L79.5,71.9l-1.8-2.8v3.3v25.3H74V64.2h4.2l17.1,26l1.8,2.8v-3.3V64.2H100.9 M101.9,63.2 h-5.8v26.4L78.7,63.2H73v35.6h5.7V72.5l17.4,26.3h5.8V63.2L101.9,63.2z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M118.7,64.2v33.7h-3.8V64.2H118.7 M119.7,63.2h-5.8v35.7h5.8V63.2L119.7,63.2z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M148.5,63.9L148.5,63.9c3.8,0,7,1,9.7,2.9c2.3,1.8,3.9,4,4.9,6.7H159c-0.9-1.8-2.2-3.3-3.9-4.5 c-2-1.2-4.3-1.8-6.8-1.8c-2.4,0-4.6,0.6-6.5,1.7s-3.5,2.7-4.6,4.8c-1.1,2-1.6,4.5-1.6,7.3c0,2.9,0.5,5.4,1.6,7.4 c1.1,2.1,2.5,3.7,4.7,4.9c1.9,1.1,4.3,1.6,6.9,1.6c3.3,0,6-1,8.3-3s3.7-4.8,4.1-8.2l0.1-1.1h-1.1h-12.1v-2.2h16v4.4 c-0.4,2.5-1.3,4.7-2.6,6.7c-1.5,2.1-3.4,3.7-5.5,4.8c-2.2,1.2-4.8,1.8-7.8,1.8c-3.3,0-6.2-0.7-8.7-2.2c-2.4-1.3-4.3-3.3-5.8-6 c-1.4-2.5-2.1-5.5-2.1-8.9s0.7-6.4,2.1-8.9c1.3-2.5,3.3-4.6,5.7-6c2.6-1.5,5.5-2.2,8.7-2.2C148.2,63.9,148.4,63.9,148.5,63.9 M148.5,62.9c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5,0c-3.5,0-6.5,0.8-9.2,2.3c-2.6,1.5-4.7,3.7-6.1,6.4c-1.5,2.7-2.2,5.9-2.2,9.4s0.7,6.7,2.2,9.4 c1.5,2.7,3.5,4.9,6.2,6.4c2.6,1.5,5.7,2.3,9.2,2.3c3.1,0,5.9-0.6,8.3-1.9c2.4-1.2,4.3-3,5.8-5.1c1.5-2.2,2.4-4.6,2.8-7.2v-5.5h-18 v4.2h13.1c-0.4,3.2-1.7,5.8-3.8,7.6c-2.1,1.9-4.6,2.8-7.6,2.8c-2.4,0-4.6-0.5-6.4-1.5c-1.9-1.1-3.3-2.5-4.3-4.5 c-1-1.9-1.5-4.3-1.5-7c0-2.6,0.5-4.9,1.5-6.8s2.4-3.4,4.2-4.4c1.8-1.1,3.8-1.6,6-1.6c2.4,0,4.5,0.6,6.3,1.7c1.8,1.2,3,2.7,3.8,4.6 h6.1c-0.9-3.6-2.8-6.4-5.6-8.5C156,64,152.7,62.9,148.5,62.9L148.5,62.9z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M192.4,64.7l12.4,33.1h-4.1l-2.5-7l-0.2-0.7h-0.7h-15.1h-0.7l-0.2,0.7l-2.5,7h-4l12.4-33.1H192.4 M182.4,87.6 h1.4h11.8h1.4l-0.5-1.3l-5.9-16.7l-0.9-2.7l-0.9,2.7l-5.9,16.7L182.4,87.6 M193.1,63.7h-6.6l-13.2,35.1h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7 h6.2L193.1,63.7L193.1,63.7z M183.8,86.6l5.9-16.7l5.9,16.7H183.8L183.8,86.6z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="kupiec-outlined">
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M27.6,126.6l-14.3,15.9l-0.6,0.7l0.6,0.7l14.3,16.3h-4.4L9.4,144.1l-0.6-0.8l0.6-0.7l13.9-16H27.6 M7.6,126.6 v15.3v2.7v0.1v15.5H3.9v-33.6L7.6,126.6 M29.8,125.6h-7L8.6,141.9v-16.3H2.9v35.6h5.7v-16.5l14.1,16.5h7.1l-15.8-18L29.8,125.6 L29.8,125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M65.4,126.6v20.2c0,4.6-1.2,8.1-3.5,10.4c-2.3,2.3-5.5,3.5-9.3,3.5s-6.9-1.2-9.2-3.5s-3.4-5.7-3.4-10.4v-20.2 h3.7v20.2c0,3.4,0.8,6,2.3,7.8s3.8,2.6,6.7,2.6c2.7,0,4.9-0.9,6.6-2.6c1.6-1.8,2.3-4.3,2.3-7.8v-20.2H65.4 M66.4,125.6h-5.8v21.2 c0,3.2-0.7,5.5-2.1,7.1c-1.4,1.5-3.3,2.3-5.8,2.3s-4.5-0.7-5.9-2.3s-2.1-3.9-2.1-7.1v-21.2H39v21.2c0,4.9,1.2,8.6,3.7,11.1 s5.8,3.8,9.9,3.8s7.5-1.3,10-3.8s3.8-6.2,3.8-11.1L66.4,125.6L66.4,125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M90.3,126.6c3.9,0,6.8,0.9,8.6,2.6c2,1.9,2.9,4.2,2.8,7.3c0,3.1-1,5.5-2.9,7.3s-4.8,2.6-8.5,2.6h-6.4h-1v1 v12.9h-3.8v-33.7L90.3,126.6 M82.9,143.7h1h5.8c2.9,0,5-0.7,6.4-2.1c1.2-1.2,1.8-2.9,1.7-5.1c0-2.2-0.7-4-2-5.3s-3.3-1.9-6.1-1.9 h-5.8h-1v1v12.4L82.9,143.7 M90.3,125.6H78.1v35.7h5.8v-13.9h6.4c4,0,7.1-1,9.2-2.9c2.1-1.9,3.2-4.6,3.2-8c0.1-3.4-1-6-3.1-8 C97.5,126.5,94.4,125.6,90.3,125.6L90.3,125.6z M83.9,142.7v-12.4h5.8c2.5,0,4.3,0.5,5.4,1.6c1.1,1.1,1.7,2.6,1.7,4.6 c0.1,4.1-2.3,6.2-7.1,6.2L83.9,142.7L83.9,142.7z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M117.7,126.6v33.7h-3.8v-33.7H117.7 M118.7,125.6h-5.8v35.7h5.8V125.6L118.7,125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M150.2,126.6v2.6h-13.7h-1v1V141v1h1h12.1v2.5h-12.1h-1v1v11v1h1h13.7v2.7h-18.5v-33.6L150.2,126.6 M151.2,125.6h-20.5v35.6h20.5v-4.7h-14.7v-11h13.1V141h-13.1v-10.8h14.7V125.6L151.2,125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" style="opacity: .5" d="M178.3,126.3c3.9,0,7.1,1,9.7,3c2.4,1.8,4.1,4.2,5.2,7.2h-4.1c-0.9-2-2.3-3.7-4.1-4.9 c-1.9-1.4-4.4-2.1-7.4-2.1c-2.3,0-4.4,0.6-6.2,1.7c-1.9,1.1-3.3,2.8-4.3,4.9c-1,1.9-1.5,4.3-1.5,7.2c0,2.7,0.5,5,1.5,7.2 c1.1,2,2.5,3.7,4.2,4.9l0,0l0,0c2,1.2,4,1.7,6.2,1.7c2.9,0,5.3-0.7,7.4-2.1c1.8-1.3,3.2-3,4.1-4.9h4.1c-1,3-2.7,5.4-5.2,7.2 c-2.7,2.1-6.2,3.1-10.3,3.1c-3.1,0-6-0.7-8.5-2.2c-2.4-1.4-4.3-3.4-5.6-6c-1.3-2.5-2-5.6-2-8.9c0-3.4,0.7-6.4,2-8.9 c1.4-2.6,3.2-4.6,5.6-6c2.5-1.4,5.4-2.2,8.5-2.2C178,126.3,178.2,126.3,178.3,126.3 M178.3,125.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5,0 c-3.4,0-6.4,0.8-9,2.3c-2.6,1.5-4.6,3.7-6,6.4s-2.1,5.9-2.1,9.4s0.7,6.7,2.1,9.4s3.4,4.9,6,6.4s5.6,2.3,9,2.3 c4.3,0,8-1.1,10.9-3.3s4.9-5.2,5.9-9h-6.1c-0.8,2.1-2.2,3.8-4,5.1c-1.9,1.3-4.1,1.9-6.8,1.9c-2.1,0-4-0.6-5.7-1.6 c-1.6-1.1-2.9-2.6-3.9-4.5c-0.9-1.9-1.4-4.1-1.4-6.7s0.4-4.9,1.4-6.8c0.9-2,2.2-3.5,3.9-4.5c1.7-1.1,3.6-1.6,5.7-1.6 c2.7,0,5,0.6,6.8,1.9c1.8,1.2,3.2,2.9,4,5.1h6.1c-1-3.8-3-6.8-5.9-9C185.9,126.4,182.5,125.3,178.3,125.3L178.3,125.3z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="main-logo">
            <a href="{{ $person_1->permalink }}">
                <g id="jaciubek">
                    <path d="M21.6,0.7v25.9c0,3.2-0.9,5.7-2.7,7.5s-4.3,2.7-7.4,2.7c-3.4,0-6.1-1-8.1-3S0.5,29,0.5,25.4h5.7c0,1.9,0.4,3.5,1.2,4.5 s2.1,1.6,3.8,1.6c1.6,0,2.8-0.5,3.5-1.4s1.1-2.1,1.1-3.5V0.7H21.6z"/>
                    <path d="M50.5,1.3h-6.6L30.7,36.4h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7h6.2L50.5,1.3z M41.2,24.2l5.9-16.7L53,24.2H41.2z"/>
                    <path d="M99.9,3.7c2.9,2.2,4.9,5.2,5.9,9h-6.1c-0.8-2.2-2.2-3.9-4-5.1c-1.8-1.3-4.1-1.9-6.8-1.9c-2.1,0-4,0.5-5.7,1.6 c-1.7,1-3,2.5-3.9,4.5c-1,1.9-1.4,4.2-1.4,6.8s0.5,4.8,1.4,6.7c1,1.9,2.3,3.4,3.9,4.5c1.7,1,3.6,1.6,5.7,1.6 c2.7,0,4.9-0.6,6.8-1.9c1.8-1.3,3.2-3,4-5.1h6.1c-1,3.8-3,6.8-5.9,9s-6.5,3.3-10.9,3.3c-3.4,0-6.4-0.8-9-2.3s-4.6-3.7-6-6.4 s-2.1-5.9-2.1-9.4s0.7-6.7,2.1-9.4c1.4-2.7,3.4-4.9,6-6.4c2.6-1.6,5.6-2.3,9-2.3C93.3,0.4,97,1.5,99.9,3.7z"/>
                    <rect x="116.6" y="0.7" width="5.8" height="35.7"/>
                    <path d="M139.9,0.7v21.2c0,3.2,0.7,5.5,2.1,7.1c1.4,1.6,3.4,2.3,5.9,2.3s4.4-0.8,5.8-2.3c1.4-1.5,2.1-3.9,2.1-7.1V0.7h5.8v21.2 c0,4.9-1.3,8.6-3.8,11.1s-5.9,3.8-10,3.8s-7.4-1.3-9.9-3.8s-3.7-6.2-3.7-11.1V0.7H139.9z"/>
                    <path d="M197.3,21.1c-1.3-1.6-3.1-2.6-5.3-3.1c1.9-0.5,3.5-1.4,4.7-2.8c1.2-1.4,1.8-3.2,1.8-5.5c0-2.8-1-5-2.9-6.6 s-4.7-2.4-8.2-2.4h-14v35.7h14.2c3.8,0,6.7-0.9,8.7-2.6c2-1.7,3-4.1,3-7C199.3,24.6,198.6,22.7,197.3,21.1z M179.2,5.4h6.9 c2.2,0,3.8,0.5,4.8,1.4c1.1,0.9,1.6,2.2,1.6,3.9c0,1.7-0.5,3-1.6,4c-1.1,0.9-2.6,1.4-4.6,1.4h-7.1L179.2,5.4L179.2,5.4z M191.6,30.2c-1.2,1-2.9,1.5-5.1,1.5h-7.3V20.3h7.3c2.2,0,3.9,0.5,5.1,1.5c1.2,1,1.8,2.4,1.8,4.2S192.8,29.2,191.6,30.2z"/>
                    <polygon points="215.6,5.4 215.6,16.2 228.7,16.2 228.7,20.6 215.6,20.6 215.6,31.7 230.2,31.7 230.2,36.4 209.8,36.4 209.8,0.7 230.2,0.7 230.2,5.4"/>
                    <polygon points="252.1,18.4 267.9,36.4 260.8,36.4 246.7,19.9 246.7,36.4 240.9,36.4 240.9,0.7 246.7,0.7 246.7,17.1 260.9,0.7 267.9,0.7"/>
                    <rect id="jaciubek_hover" x="0" y="0" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;" id="e1_rectangle" width="100%" height="33%"/>
                </g>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ $person_2->permalink }}">
                <g id="janiga">
                    <path d="M21.6,63.1V89c0,3.2-0.9,5.7-2.7,7.5s-4.3,2.7-7.4,2.7c-3.4,0-6.1-1-8.1-3s-2.9-4.8-2.9-8.4h5.7c0,2,0.4,3.5,1.2,4.5 s2.1,1.6,3.8,1.6c1.6,0,2.8-0.5,3.5-1.4s1.1-2.1,1.1-3.5V63.1H21.6z"/>
                    <path d="M50.5,63.7h-6.6L30.7,98.8h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7h6.2L50.5,63.7z M41.2,86.6l5.9-16.7L53,86.6H41.2z"/>
                    <polygon points="101.9,98.8 96.1,98.8 78.7,72.5 78.7,98.8 73,98.8 73,63.2 78.7,63.2 96.1,89.6 96.1,63.2 101.9,63.2"/>
                    <rect x="113.9" y="63.2" width="5.8" height="35.7"/>
                    <path d="M158.8,66c2.8,2.1,4.7,4.9,5.6,8.5h-6.1c-0.8-1.9-2-3.4-3.8-4.6c-1.8-1.1-3.9-1.7-6.3-1.7c-2.2,0-4.2,0.5-6,1.6 c-1.8,1-3.2,2.5-4.2,4.4s-1.5,4.2-1.5,6.8c0,2.7,0.5,5.1,1.5,7c1,2,2.4,3.4,4.3,4.5c1.8,1,4,1.5,6.4,1.5c3,0,5.5-0.9,7.6-2.8 c2.1-1.8,3.4-4.4,3.8-7.6H147v-4.2h18v5.5c-0.4,2.6-1.3,5-2.8,7.2c-1.5,2.1-3.4,3.9-5.8,5.1c-2.4,1.3-5.2,1.9-8.3,1.9 c-3.5,0-6.6-0.8-9.2-2.3c-2.7-1.5-4.7-3.7-6.2-6.4c-1.5-2.7-2.2-5.9-2.2-9.4s0.7-6.7,2.2-9.4c1.4-2.7,3.5-4.9,6.1-6.4 c2.7-1.5,5.7-2.3,9.2-2.3C152.4,62.8,155.9,63.9,158.8,66z"/>
                    <path d="M193.1,63.7h-6.6l-13.2,35.1h6.2l2.7-7.7h15.1l2.7,7.7h6.2L193.1,63.7z M183.8,86.6l5.9-16.7l5.9,16.7H183.8z"/>
                    <rect id="janiga_hover" x="0" y="33%" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;" id="e1_rectangle" width="77%" height="33%"/>
                </g>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ $person_3->permalink }}">
                <g id="kupiec">
                    <polygon points="14,143.2 29.8,161.2 22.7,161.2 8.6,144.7 8.6,161.2 2.9,161.2 2.9,125.6 8.6,125.6 8.6,141.9 22.8,125.6 29.8,125.6"/>
                    <path d="M44.7,125.6v21.2c0,3.2,0.7,5.5,2.1,7.1c1.4,1.6,3.4,2.3,5.9,2.3s4.4-0.8,5.8-2.3c1.4-1.6,2.1-3.9,2.1-7.1v-21.2h5.8v21.2 c0,4.9-1.3,8.6-3.8,11.1s-5.9,3.8-10,3.8s-7.4-1.3-9.9-3.8s-3.7-6.2-3.7-11.1v-21.2H44.7z"/>
                    <path d="M99.6,128.5c-2.1-2-5.2-2.9-9.3-2.9H78.1v35.7h5.8v-13.9h6.4c4,0,7.1-1,9.2-2.9c2.1-1.9,3.2-4.6,3.2-8 C102.8,133.1,101.7,130.5,99.6,128.5z M89.7,142.7h-5.8v-12.4h5.8c2.5,0,4.3,0.5,5.4,1.6c1.1,1.1,1.7,2.6,1.7,4.6 C96.9,140.6,94.5,142.7,89.7,142.7z"/>
                    <rect x="112.9" y="125.6" width="5.8" height="35.7"/>
                    <polygon points="136.5,130.2 136.5,141 149.6,141 149.6,145.5 136.5,145.5 136.5,156.5 151.2,156.5 151.2,161.2 130.7,161.2 130.7,125.6 151.2,125.6 151.2,130.2"/>
                    <path d="M188.7,128.5c2.9,2.2,4.9,5.2,5.9,9h-6.1c-0.8-2.2-2.2-3.9-4-5.1c-1.8-1.3-4.1-1.9-6.8-1.9c-2.1,0-4,0.5-5.7,1.6 c-1.7,1-3,2.5-3.9,4.5c-1,1.9-1.4,4.2-1.4,6.8s0.5,4.8,1.4,6.7c1,1.9,2.3,3.4,3.9,4.5c1.7,1,3.6,1.6,5.7,1.6 c2.7,0,4.9-0.6,6.8-1.9c1.8-1.3,3.2-3,4-5.1h6.1c-1,3.8-3,6.8-5.9,9s-6.6,3.3-10.9,3.3c-3.4,0-6.4-0.8-9-2.3s-4.6-3.7-6-6.4 s-2.1-5.9-2.1-9.4s0.7-6.7,2.1-9.4c1.4-2.7,3.4-4.9,6-6.4c2.6-1.5,5.6-2.3,9-2.3C182.2,125.2,185.8,126.3,188.7,128.5z"/>
                    <rect id="kupiec_hover" x="0" y="66%" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;" id="e1_rectangle" width="77%" height="33%"/>
                </g>
            </a>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And there is code in JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var timeout = 2000;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.header-col #j-1').css('opacity', '1');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.header-col #j-2').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 400);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.header-col #k').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 800);
    }, timeout);



    var timeout = 3000;
    $('#jaciubek').children().each(function () {
        var self = this;

        timeout += 100;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('opacity', '1');
        }, timeout);
    });

    timeout = 3500;
    $('#janiga').children().each(function () {
        var self = this;

        timeout += 100;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('opacity', '1');
        }, timeout);
    });

    timeout = 4000;
    $('#kupiec').children().each(function () {
        var self = this;

        timeout += 100;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('opacity', '1');
        }, timeout);
    });
});
```

Anyone have some suggestion how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways.  For instance, you could use a cookie. But the more modern way is to use the [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Before you run the animation, do a check something like this:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("SeenAnimation"))
   return; // Exit before starting the animation
```

And in your animation code, do the following when you animation has finished (or "enough" has been seen by the user).

```
window.localStorage.setItem("SeenAnimation", true);
```

If you only want this setting to be remembered for the current session, rather than forever, then use `window.sessionStorage` instead.

Comment: After adding your proposed code into mine i've got an error: uncaught typeerror: can't access property "setitem", window.sessionstorage is undefined.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've got it. I tried to write without window on the beginning only sessionStorage.setItem and next sessionStorage.getItem and its working. Much thanks for help.